# Pyspark: Identify the arrayType column from the the Struct and call udf to convert array to string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-conversion, accelerator

I am creating an accelerator where it migrates the data from source to destination. For Example, I will pick the data from an API and will migrate the data to csv. I have faced issues with handling arraytype while data is converted to csv. I have used withColumn and concat_ws method(i.e., *df1=df.withColumn('films',F.concat_ws(':',F.col("films")))* **films is the arraytype column** ) for this conversion and it worked. Now I wanted this to happen dynamically. I mean, without specifying the column name, is there a way that I can pick the column name from struct which have the arraytype and then call the udf?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of the columns using [df.schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.schema.html). Depending on the type of the column you can apply [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html) or not:

```python
data = [["test1", "test2", [1,2,3], ["a","b","c"]]]
schema= ["col1", "col2", "arr1", "arr2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

array_cols = [F.concat_ws(":", c.name).alias(c.name) \
    for c in df.schema if isinstance(c.dataType, T.ArrayType) ]
other_cols = [F.col(c.name) \
    for c in df.schema if not isinstance(c.dataType, T.ArrayType) ]

df = df.select(other_cols + array_cols)
```

Result:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| col1| col2| arr1| arr2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|test1|test2|1:2:3|a:b:c|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```